# Mailjet API Java metadata eclipse issue breakdown

Tags: java, eclipse, import, metadata, mailjet

I 'll get straight to the point
After refactoring(a great mistake) at Eclipse my class from Mailjet API implementation about metadata (API Configuration) from [here](https://dev.mailjet.com/email-api/v3/metadata/) , i keep getting the compiler broken, unable to recognise the specific import, but also encountering the same issue at my next tries at different classes, implementing other areas of Mailjet API. 
I will try to show the issue by quoting a part of the code:

```
import com.mailjet.api.client.MailJetApiCallException;
import com.mailjet.api.client.MailJetApiClient;
import com.mailjet.api.client.config.MailJetClientConfigurationException;
import com.mailjet.api.client.model.ResultSet;
import com.mailjet.api.model.v3.apikeytotals.ApiKeyTotals;
import com.mailjet.api.model.v3.metadata.Metadata;
import com.mailjet.api.model.v3.metadata.MetadataProperty;


@Path("/")
public class Metadatanew {

    @Path("/metadataview/{key}")
    @GET
    public Response metadataview(@PathParam("key") String key) {

         MailJetApiClient cl=null;
         Metadata thismetadata=null;
         String all = "";
        try {
            cl = MailjetUsersRest.createClient();
            key = "SOMEKEY";
            thismetadata=cl.createCall(Metadata.List).identifiedBy(MetadataProperty.UNIQUEKEY, key).execute();

        } catch (MailJetClientConfigurationException | MailJetApiCallException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


            return Response.status(200).entity(all).build();
        return null;

        }
```

The next method also does not recognise the Metadata class and so on. As if my compiler breaks down at the "MetadataProperty.UNIQUEKEY" point, at which it simply does not make it live blue and italics, does not even recognise common mistakes of all kinds after that point as well in the whole code after.
The strange thing in the whole issue is that when i write MetadataProperty and "." it shows all the correct stat possible enterings.

In my next class implementation right after the breakdown of Metadata, about Domain Statistics, i have to write

```
cl = MailjetUsersRest.createClient();
    ResultSet<com.mailjet.api.model.v3.domainstatistics.DomainStatistics> dom=cl.createCall(com.mailjet.api.model.v3.domainstatistics.DomainStatistics.List).execute();
```

instead of the normal i suppose (which is considered as wrong from eclipse)

```
cl = MailjetUsersRest.createClient();
        ResultSet<DomainStatistics> dom=cl.createCall(DomainStatistics.List).execute();
```

All my written classes before Metadata are functioning correctly in the right above way

The error i get at the first line where the package is stated is :

> The type com.mailjet.api.model.v3.customtypes.Property cannot be
>   resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Any help will be greatly appreciated

ps. i deleted and clean installed Eclipse, even another version, i made new projects and reloaded all libraries needed from scratch and i have tried to google the issue without any success